# How to make a draw rectangle 2px larger on each side than the recorded rectangle. C#

Tags: c#, canvas, coordinates, rectangles

Hey so I'm currently using this post to create rectangles on a canvas and was wandering how i could make the drawn rectangle 2px larger than the actual rectangle recorded. Is this possible and if so how would i do this have been trying to work it out for a while now would be really useful to finally have a solution.

```
Point startPos;      // mouse-down position
Point currentPos;    // current mouse position
bool drawing;        // busy drawing
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();  // previous rectangles

private Rectangle getRectangle() {
    return new Rectangle(
        Math.Min(startPos.X, currentPos.X),
        Math.Min(startPos.Y, currentPos.Y),
        Math.Abs(startPos.X - currentPos.X),
        Math.Abs(startPos.Y - currentPos.Y));
}

private void canevas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    currentPos = startPos = e.Location;
    drawing = true;
}

private void canevas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    currentPos = e.Location;
    if (drawing) canevas.Invalidate();
}

private void canevas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (drawing) {
        drawing = false;
        var rc = getRectangle();
        if (rc.Width > 0 && rc.Height > 0) rectangles.Add(rc);
        canevas.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void canevas_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
    if (rectangles.Count > 0) e.Graphics.DrawRectangles(Pens.Black, rectangles.ToArray());
    if (drawing) e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, getRectangle());
}
```

just for reference this code came from this post

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060446/how-to-draw-rectangle-on-mousedown-move-c-sharp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `getRectangle` method you just need to change the values that you use in the constructor for the `Rectangle`. Since the third one refers to the width property, you add the number of pixels to `Math.Abs(startPos.X - currentPos.X)`.After this the check `if (rc.Width > 0)` is useless for obvious reasons.